# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath with iOS13 // Cocoapod // Swift 5.0

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, dyld

I really can't find a way to solve my probleme.
To explain it quickly: I had an app that retrived data from Firebase with some Frameworks and this app worked fine. But recently, the app crash when I build it on my iPhone, but not on the Simulator. I updated cocoapods to see if it solve the probleme but no.
When I try running it on the device I get this error :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher    
Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0F2C2461-A68B-4ABA-A604-B88E6E9D1BB1/AppName.app/AppName
Reason: image not found
```

I've tried different solutions, but none of them really worked. Please help me.

Comment: Is the `.framework` in the app bundle?  What is rpath set to?

Comment: are you deploying to your device using a free or paid apple developer account? that might be the issue.

Comment: I'm using a free account but it worked before so I don't think that it might be the issue.

Comment: Where do I have to check for the .framework in the app bundle. Sorry because I'm new in coding, so maybe my questions are stupids.